# eigen vector that orthogonal to each other, symmetry matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

symmetry matrix $\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 1 & 1 \\
      1 & 0 & 1 \\
      1 & 1 & 0  \end{array}\right) $
one of  eigen value is $\lambda_1=2$ and one of eigen vector is $x_1=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} \frac{1}{\sqrt3} \\
       \frac{1}{\sqrt3}  \\
       \frac{1}{\sqrt3}  \end{array}\right) $
then i found the two other eigen value is $\lambda_2=-1 $ & $\lambda_3=-1$
but the question want eigen vector that is orthogonal to each other and has magnitude $
|x_2|=|x_3|=1$ 
here how can i find the two other eigen vector that orthogonal to each other?
using usual computation $x=-y-z, i cant find the vector that is orthogonal to each other and with magnitude 1.
using trial and error?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}  \\    \frac{-1}{\sqrt{6}}  \\    \frac{-1}{\sqrt{6}}  \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
   0  \\    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\    \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}

Edit: Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{bmatrix}
   2 \\    -1 \\    -1  \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
   -1  \\    2  \\    -1  \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
   -1  \\    -1 \\    2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}
are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $-1$ and between them they span a space of dimension $2$, so we need to find a linear combination that is orthogonal the first one 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{bmatrix}
  2  \\    -1  \\    -1  \\
\end{bmatrix} \cdot ( \alpha
\begin{bmatrix}
   2 \\    -1  \\    -1  \\
\end{bmatrix}+ \beta
\begin{bmatrix}
   -1  \\    2  \\    -1  \\
\end{bmatrix}+ \gamma
\begin{bmatrix}
   -1  \\    -1  \\    2  \\
\end{bmatrix} ) .
\end{eqnarray*}
This gives $ 6 \alpha -3 \beta -3 \gamma=0$ and $ \alpha=1, \beta=-2, \gamma=0$ will do, and now you just need to normalise.

Comment: thanks but can you explain how to get this? is this using gram-schmidt?

Comment: thanks but how did you get eigen vector? i got  $\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{bmatrix}
   -1\\    1 \\    0  \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
   -1  \\    0  \\    1  \\
\end{bmatrix}\end{eqnarray*}$ ? and why has to be ortogonal to first one? i have no clue :/

Comment: The above arguement works just as well with the vectors
\begin{eqnarray*} \begin{bmatrix}    0\\    1 \\    -1  \\ \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}     1  \\    -1  \\    0  \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}    -1\\    0 \\    1  \\ \end{bmatrix}, \end{eqnarray*}. 
The question requests an orthonormal basis, so we need to find two linear combinations of these vectors whose dot product gives zero (orthogonal).

Comment: when i tried to compute it using gram schmidt, when $v_2=x_2-<x2.x1>x1$ here $<x2.x1>$ produce $0$? and all the vector seem already linear independent to each other?

Comment: i choose $\begin{eqnarray*} x_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\begin {bmatrix}    1\\    1 \\    1  \\ \end{bmatrix}, x_2= \begin {bmatrix}    -1  \\    1  \\    0 \\ \end{bmatrix}\end{eqnarray*}$ and using grram schmidt, $\begin{eqnarray*} \begin{bmatrix}   -1\\    1 \\    0  \\ \end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}     1  \\    1  \\    1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \end{eqnarray*}$ it gives zero

Comment: sorry can i ask again to clear my confusion, why it has to be orthogonal to $\begin{eqnarray*} \begin{bmatrix}    2\\    -1 \\    -1  \\ \end{bmatrix},\end{eqnarray*}$ and how can you get the value of $\lambda ,\gamma ,\beta$?

Comment: $\alpha=1, \beta=-2, \gamma=0$ btw this does not produce 0? do you mean $\alpha=1, \beta=0, \gamma=2$?